# Azure Web App - Linux/Laravel : Point domain to folder

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I just started using Azure and created a Linux web app.

I followed the domain DNS tutorial and setup my domain : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain

I used the custom domain - text type

test.com does not point to the folder /site/wwwroot on the app.

I placed the site folder in /wwwroot

However, in laravel - the actual site is in /sitefolder/public

How do I point to this folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with DNS. What you need to do is create a `.htaccess` file containing the following code and place this file in Laravel's root directory.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

***More on this:***

[How can I remove "public/index.php" in the url generated laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23837933/how-can-i-remove-public-index-php-in-the-url-generated-laravel)

[Apache rewrite for Laravel /public](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15498513/apache-rewrite-for-laravel-public/)